# Trying to use 3 lists to iterate and store data in a 4th list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I'll try to explain this the best way I can. I have 4 lists, each of variable length. I want to take input into `list1` by each element in `listx`, `listy`, and `listz`.

Essentially creating a loop that loops through another loop, so for `a` in `listx` and position `1` in `listy` and position `1` in `listz`, is what the data you want to store.

Then loop back for `a` in `listx` and position `1` in `listy` to position `2` in `listz` and take that data. Then loop again for `a` in `listx` and position `2` in `listy` to position `1` in `listz`, and so on.

```
listx = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]
listy = [1,2,3,4]
listz = [1,2]
list1 = [[0*5],[0*5]]

def getListData():
    for pos in range(len(listx)):
        for pos in range(listy):
            for pos in range(listz): 
                list1 = input("Enter the number for position %s in pos %s in list %s" % (listz[pos], listy[pos], listx[pos]))
```

This is what I've tried with no success. Also tried with zip but I couldn't get that to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't understand your explanation. Could you post initial values for each list (list1, listx, listy, listz) and the final value(s) you're expecting? It would make it a lot easier to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well for starters you're using `pos` to refer to three different variables! I'm not certain what you're asking, but I'd suggest at least switching to something like `pos_x`, `pos_y`, and `pos_z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were actually rather close, but made some simple mistakes. First, you don't need to set `list1` equal to anything special initially; an empty list will do. Next, you used `pos` as a variable in all layers of your nested loop. This confuses the hell out of python; use different names if you're referring to different things. Finally, you use `list1 =` instead of `list1.append()`. Using `=` will clear the value of `list1` and set it to whatever is on the other side of that `=` sign; `append` will add to the list, which seems to be what you want.

Also, I've made the code a bit more pythonic in a few ways. Instead of a list of characters for `listx`, it is now just a string, as strings are iterable. And I've used the `for x in iterable` idiom rather than the wordier `for x in range(len(iterable))`. These weren't mistakes as such, but I think the code I've produced is nicer.

```
listx = 'abcdefghijkl'
listy = [1,2,3,4]
listz = [1,2]
list1 = []

def getListData():
    for x in listx:
        for y in listy:
            for z in listz: 
                list1.append(input("xvalue: {}, yvalue: {}, zvalue: {}".format(x, y, z))
```

Something to note: if you're expecting the input to be an integer, you might want to try `int(input())` instead (i.e. cast the result as an int). By default it is interpreted as a string.

Comment: I appreciate it, I figured I was close. The end goal is a program that logs the winning numbers of the Powerball for a year into a file. So listx is actually months of the year, y is the number of weeks and z is the drawings per week. List1 is for the input data and has like 96 elements, each taking 5 numbers... Big list... Anyways I appreciate the feedback back. This helped clarify for me